# How does authentication in python work?

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2, api-key

I am trying to work on musixmatch [api](https://developer.musixmatch.com).
To get the json data I need to authenticate first,I have api key but i am unable to authenticate. 
I would like to know how to authenticate using urllib2
Thanks:

Ps:I tried doing this:

```
def download_file(url, API_KEY_BASE_64):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic "+API_KEY_BASE_64)
    return urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

here

```
url="http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?track_id=15953433"
api_key="MYAPIKEY"
```

response i got is:

```
{"message":{"header":{"status_code":401,"execute_time":0.0019550323486328,"maintenance_id":0},"body":""}}
```

Comment: Can you include your `API_KEY_BASE_64` in your question ?

Comment: Can't get give my whole api key but it looks like this
API_KEY_BASE_64="25600XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX65"

Comment: like this ? Or a sample key to test it. You can use `requests` python lib to make this api call plus i think you should include `content-type` in your api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the authentication in python, but a problem with the way the api is expecting your api key.

This page: https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation/input-parameters states that you must *always* send your api key as a parameter, so this code does exactly that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2

api_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# Note how I'm adding the api key as a parameter of the request url
url="http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?track_id=15953433&apikey={}".format(api_key)

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print response
```

PS: You could also use this library (https://github.com/monkeython/musixmatch), it wraps around the api and it seems easy to use.